# Retrieve Data from MySQL (phpmyadmin) to TextBox in visual c#

Tags: mysql, textbox, phpmyadmin

I've posted several questions regarding this but none of them really helped me... Here I go with a clearer explanation:

I put data into the SQL table, here is what type of data goes in (All of them are String type):
http://i40.tinypic.com/33kaoat.png

When I click "Submit" button - the data saves in the table when I check it from PhpMyAdmin. But now I want to retrieve this data into this next tab form when I click "Refresh" button:  http://i41.tinypic.com/34hdtv4.png

textBox5 is the textbox which I want my data to show up after I click on "Refresh" button

Here is the script I've done so far for the "Refresh" Button, but it gives me an error:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=request;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
        using (MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = mcon.CreateCommand())
        {
            mcon.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM requesttcw";
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    this.textBox5.Text = reader.GetString("UPDATE `requesttcw` SET `ID`=[value-1]");
                    this.textBox5.Text = " || ";
                    this.textBox5.Text = reader.GetString("UPDATE `requesttcw` SET `ClanName`=[value-2]");
                    this.textBox5.Text = " || ";
                    this.textBox5.Text = reader.GetString("UPDATE `requesttcw` SET `Date`=[value-3]");
                    this.textBox5.Text = " || ";
                    this.textBox5.Text = reader.GetString("UPDATE `requesttcw` SET `Type`=[value-4]");
                    this.textBox5.Text = " || ";
                    this.textBox5.Text = reader.GetString("UPDATE `requesttcw` SET `Rules`=[value-5]");
                    this.textBox5.Text = " || ";
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            mcon.Close();
        }
    }
```

The textbox I want the data to showin is called textBox5.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use a ListBox instead to show the string?

```
ListBox.Items.Add(<Your DataReader String>);
```

**Edited**

I assume that you are updating the table once and than you want to pick the updated row and show the items. If this is the case, update the table as:

```
UPDATE requesttcw SET 
  ID=value-1, 
  ClanName = Value-2,
  Date = value-3,
  Type = value-4,
  Rules = value-5
```

After that, run your select query and initialize the DataReader. With DataReader:

```
string StringToShow = dr[0] + "||" + dr[1] .....    
textBox5.Text = StringToShow;
```

Here I am assuming that you are picking a single row. If you want to continuously pick rows and keep showing, then you need to use ListBox.

Comment: How would that work? What do you mean show the "string"? Could you sketch a script of how this string could combine all these 'requesttcw' table column values and show them in this "ListBox"?

Comment: Do you want to display a concatenated type of string?

Comment: test.Items.Add(reader.GetString("UPDATE `requesttcw` SET `ID`=[value-1]"));

is this what you mean? (test is the listbox accessible name)

Comment: And yes RPK.. I want a 1 string to show all the data in 1 line then the next string show under or over that string in another line..

Comment: so this is what I added RPK (I used a ListBox called test):
          cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE 'requesttcw' SET  'ID'=value-          1,  'ClanName' = Value-2, 'Date' = value-3, 'Type' = value-4, 'Rules' = value-5";
                        string final = test.Items.Add(reader.GetString(1)) + " " + test.Items.Add(reader.GetString(2)) + " " + test.Items.Add(reader.GetString(3)) + " " + test.Items.Add(reader.GetString(4));
                        test.Items.Add(final);

Comment: Yeah, But please take a look at this ScreenShot, I want all those info to be in 1 row at the ListBox then the next data goes in another row below it, but look at this: http://i42.tinypic.com/5evjug.png

Comment: Also if its not so much to ask for, maybe I could give you my msn or xfire or something? All of this will be solved way quicker then.. If you dont mind :)

Comment: @DamageDz The image looks perfect. Now you have problem displaying it correctly. Update your original post so that I can see what you attempted.